# Abort a MySQL transaction in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

I need to *abort* a mysqli transaction if an error occurs and then write the error to my error log table. I know about:

```
mysqli::rollback()
mysqli::commit()
mysqli::begin_transaction()
```

I think I need to use `mysqli::rollback()` but sometimes queries processed are not part of a transaction how would I handle this?

Thank you

Comment: if its not a transaction, you can't roll back .. i guess you could create your own transaction handler - but that sounds horrendous to me.

Comment: Not all of the queries are transactions but some are.

Comment: wouldn't making them all transaction be the easy approach

Comment: Even for single queries?

Comment: your the one that wants rollback power - so yes. Don't bother myself :-)

Comment: I don't want to rollback as such just cancel the transaction with no changes to the database. If there were a mysqli::abort_transaction that would be perfect.

Comment: if a select or insert or update fails, then there are no changes to a db

Comment: @Dagon "wouldn't making them all transaction be the easy approach" This solved my problem, thank you.